# How one can get input or access elements from index.html in Angular 8 component?

Tags: java, angular, servlets

I am new to Angular technology and trying to embed an Angular chart component inside my java servlet web application with the below code.

```
<iframe src="../angularchart/index.html" name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="80%"></iframe>
```

This brings me the required Angular charts in my web page, but I want to pass data to Angular component from my java servlet. I know the standard way is to use REST api, but in my case I only have data in my servlet and can pass the same to index.html page.Something similar to below,

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angularchart</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function chartInput()
    {
      var jsoninput = { key : value}  // dummy input populated by servlet
      return jsoninput
    }
  </script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is that can I access the function/element defined index.html from my Angular component ? or is there any other way to do ? Thanks in Advance. Please excuse me if you find anything wrong in the question.

Comment: do you have access of the angular code and the server which that code is deployed on?

Comment: I believe Angular code is compiled and integrated within my web app war. So yes, I can access the files inside the war via inputStream in java. @YashRami

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** 
use javascript `postMessage`

```
// where to send messages with postMessage
 var target_origin = 'http://www.your-domain.com';
 var form = document.getElementById('myChart');

 // button onclick handlers
 // display offsetHeight of iframe containing this document
 form.elements.button1.onclick = function() {
      parent.postMessage( {'chartClick': 'testMessage'}, target_origin );
 }
```

**option 2**
you can also set the data in localstorage and fetch that data from your servlet code

I hope it helps you out

Comment: Thanks @Yash Rami for the suggestion. At the moment, I certainly not sure on your solution. I will implement your suggestion and mark your answer as accepted if works. Thanks Again.